# How to group results by name in Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have over 20k records that are very similar and they only vary in one column value. Is there a way to group all records with the same name using `Searchkick`. I know I can group results in `elasticsearch` but not sure how to do it with `Searchkick`.

I.e., group all records with the same name and category

```rb
category    :string
name        :string
subcategory :string
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)", "[mre]" and their linked pages. Your question isn't telling us what you tried. We expect evidence of your effort, because, without that, it looks like you didn't try and want us to write a tutorial or code for you, both of which are off-topic.